# Can a exception throws the same exception?

Tags: java, exception

Sorry if this could be a stupid question but i'm learning Java and i'm experiencing some problems with exceptions. I have this code of my first project:

```
protected void makePurchase(int userId, Product item, int quantity) throws ItemNotBuyableException {        
    int id = item.getId();
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    for (int i=0; i < quantity; i++) {
        try {
            catalog.sellProduct(id);
            count++;
        }
        catch (ItemNotBuyableException e) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    orders.addOrder(new Purchase(new GregorianCalendar(), id, item, item.getPrice(), count, userId));

    if (!flag)
        throw new ItemNotBuyableException();
}
```

Is it legit?

Comment: (Without checking for minor coding errors) Why not?  You could even save the original exception and rethrow it.  (In fact, in some cases that's better, since it preserves the original exception stack trace.)

Comment: Usually, if exception occurred you will not continue your next code and need to go handling. It is better that your `sellProduct` method return corresponding value instead of exception.

Comment: Why don't you just have the method return the boolean?

Comment: @W.K.S - Then why didn't `sellProduct` return a boolean?  Why have exceptions at all?

Comment: It is a requirement of my assignment

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is legitimate.

Theoretically, you can catch it, do some more stuff that only your class knows how to do, then throw it to whoever is using you.

```
try {
    catalog.sellProduct(id);
    count++;
}
catch (ItemNotBuyableException e) {
    doMoreStuff();
    //Better let other callers know so they can handle it appropriately
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
protected void makePurchase(int userId, Product item, int quantity) throws ItemNotBuyableException {
    int id = item.getId();
    int count = 0;

    boolean flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {

        if(!catalog.sellProduct(id)) {
            flag = false;
            continue;
        }
        count++;
    }

    orders.addOrder(new Purchase(new GregorianCalendar(), id, item, item.getPrice(), count, userId));

    if (!flag)
        throw new ItemNotBuyableException();
}
```

Comment: smartmouse is running through the whole for loop before adding the order and throwing the exception. Your code bails out with the first exception (thrown by `sellProduct`).

Comment: Yes, I got It, will change

Comment: This would work, but I suggest describing the change you're proposing (changing the signature of `sellProduct`), and why you feel it's a better solution. Also, you shouldn't break out on a single item failure.

Comment: Because exception should occure in exceptional situation, but his approach looks like not exceptional. He only need breaking, not more in this situation, so for it there is no necessity to throw exception.

Comment: The better solution may be checking abnormality before loop.

Comment: I say you shouldn't break out, because you differ from the question's behavior if you do that. If there's a problem with item 5 of 10, you'd order four items, and smartmouse would order nine.

Comment: But after break for loop doesn't continue work yet, and it is to author solution equivalent one.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken on that last part, Ashot. Maybe run through an example with pen and paper.

Comment: Ahh, OK in **his** case it works 9 times, and in my case 4, OK I got it, removing :)

Comment: But anyway author's aproach is strange.

Comment: So `continue` instead of `break` is equivalent to author's code. Isn't it?

Comment: Not quite - `flag` would be true if any but the very last item failed. You could do something like `success = true` (at the top; "success" is the more descriptive name for "flag") ... `success &= catalog.sellProduct(id);`

Comment: Just a moment. Ok, in my case, in last iteration `catalog.sellProduct` return `false`, `flag` becomes `false`, `count` not incremented. 

In author's code, if exception in last iteration accured not `count++` accures, and `flag` still `false`. Really no difference I see.

Comment: What happens if the **second to last** iteration fails?

Comment: In both cases they continue with flag == false; and not incremented count.

Comment: Ahh, OK , I got it :) And in 10-th loop I made  flag to true and in his case it retains false.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, if you want please take a look to my fix.